# PHP Wordpress orderby one parameter divided by another (for example: a / b)

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by

I was wondering how to order an array of posts not by one parameter, but a division of two parameters as in `$a / $b`. Specifically, I want to have it ordered as "trending" so as a function of the variables `$likes` and `$times`.

This is the line is use for ordering by comments:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $length_of_array, 'cat' => $cat_ID, 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged );
```

Comment: Is this a wordpress question? There is no SQL in your question.

Comment: It is a php / wordpress question, I don't know how the "sql-order-by" tag got in there. However, the underlying database is in sql.